# Should stable project still use spring-boot-starter-*?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-starter

There are many Maven artifacts named `spring-boot-starter-*`. As the names imply, they are very useful for an application project to get started with Spring Boot.

**However, after the application project become stable, should it keep using these `spring-boot-starter-*`?**

My concern is that doing so uses the Maven mechanism of "transitive dependencies", and it seems to violate the suggestion in [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> Although transitive dependencies can implicitly include desired dependencies, it is a good practice to explicitly specify the dependencies you are directly using in your own source code.

For example, suppose an application project directly uses the Spring annotation `@EventListener`. The annotation is in the Maven artifact `spring-context`, and `spring-context` is included in `spring-boot-starter`. Should the application project directly specify the dependency on `spring-context` after it become stable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Boot starter artifacts are just a shorthand for including several Spring Boot artifacts at once. My company has services in production that use starter artifacts. Of course, you could replace each starter with a list of the artifacts it contains, but I think the Maven suggestion is more about unrelated transitive dependencies, such as if your application inherited Guava from some JSON library as a transitive dependency.

When the transitive dependencies all come from the same source and are designed to work together, I don't think it's a problem. At least, I don't see it as such.